# Quick parameter like function for strings in java

Tags: java, string, parameters, prepared-statement, replace

Im delphi programmer and used to use Java quite a bit a long while ago and now back onto a project in java again and im sure that there was a function or object that could be used to basically create a string with parameters and would replace said params just like PreparedStatement.  Now for the life of me i cannot remember what this function is called or even if it exists outside of PreparedStatement or am i imagining things ???

For example, i want to take a string like this:

String ss = "(CODE, CATEGEORY, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (:CODE, :CATEGEORY, :DESCRIPTION)";

and be able to do this

```
ss.setParam(0, "thisValue");
ss.setParam(1, "thus_value");
```

etc...

Any ideas

Comment: Steve has what you're looking for. You're going to be annoyed that you can't do ParamByName, but it works just the same. Delphi handled that better IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat(
    "(CODE, CATEGEORY, DESCRIPTION) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2})");

System.out.println(mf.format("thisValue", "thatValue", "theOtherValue"));
```

Comment: THATs the one i was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @Brendan, if this is to be executed as SQL, make sure you protect yourself against injection attacks. Using a PreparedStatement will do that for you.

Comment: Its mostly internal for this.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, they are called PreparedStatements.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO myTable " +
    "(CODE, CATEGORY, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
pstmt.setString(1, "thisValue")
pstmt.setString(2, "thus_value",
pstmt.setString(3, "My description");
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about 'StringBuffer' ? If yes, you can simply append your query to it and create a query.

Comment: Welll I think its MessageFormat. Infact I got to know something like MessageFormat existed, just now. Should thank all for this !!! :)